# How will GCM handle all queueing and delivery for messages to Android applications?

Tags: android

If multiple PUSH messages are sent to the same device, then how is the queuing working in GCM.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation, should you wish to read it: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html#collapsible

> Note: There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync.